# Bulk Import Material Images

Tags: materials, import

I have an object that has several materials, with several image maps. I store the mesh on my computer, but I store these images on an external HD with more space.

Now, I'm editing the mesh and I want to import all these images at once in order to populate the material image texture nodes quickly, rather than having to go and navigate each one at a time. Is this possible? [image]